# Pad Start function in 2D array map is returning an error

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I have a 2D array that looks something like this:

```
const numbers = [
  [500], [300], [800]
  ];
```

I would like for this to return a 1D array like this: [0500, 0300, 0800]

```
const res = numbers.map(function (r) {
  return r[0].padStart(4, '0');
})

Logger.log(res);
```

Where am I going wrong? The error is TypeError: r[0].padStart is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the error is because the `padStart` function works only on string.

> The padStart() method in JavaScript is used to pad a string with
> another string until it reaches the given length. The padding is
> applied from the left end of the string.

There are multiple ways to approach your concern:

**1st approach:** To manually make the array as a string:

```
function myFunction1() {
  const numbers = [["500"], ["300"], ["800"]];
  const res = numbers.map(function (r) {
    return r[0].padStart(4, '0');
  })

  Logger.log(res);
}
```

**2nd approach:** To use function `toString()` to convert the integer for the `padStart()` function to work:

```
function myFunction2() {
  const numbers = [[500], [300], [800]];
  const res = numbers.map(function (r) {
    return r[0].toString().padStart(4, '0');
  })

  Logger.log(res);
}
```

Reference: [JavaScript padStart() Method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-padstart-method/)